# Why does $\mathscr{P}_2$ being isomorphic to $R^3$ imply that a constantwise addition of objects in $\mathscr{P}_2$ is an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, vector-space-isomorphism

Why does saying that $\mathscr{P}_2$ is isomorphic to $R^3$ immediately prove that a constant-wise addition of objects in $\mathscr{P}_2$ is an inner product?

What I mean by constant-wise addition is this operation:

let $p(x) = a+bx+cx^2$ and let $q(x) = d + ex + fx^2$. The operation in question is: $\langle p(x),q(x)\rangle = ad + be + cf $

To show that that operation is an inner product on $\mathscr{P}_2$, we need only show that the dot product in $R^3$ is an inner product, because $\mathscr{P}_2$ is isomorphic to $R^3$ (and the dot product is indeed an inner product on $R^2$).

Why is that? What significance does $\mathscr{P}_2$ being isomorphic to $R^3$ have in this context?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\phi: \mathscr P_2 \to \Bbb R^3$ be the isomorphism of vector spaces given by $\phi(a + bx + cx^2) = (a,b,c)$.  Let $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\Bbb R^3} : \Bbb R^3 \times \Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$ denote the usual dot-product.  Your "constant-wise addition" can be written as the map $( \cdot , \cdot): \mathscr P_2 \times \mathscr P_2 \to \Bbb R$ defined by
$$
(p,q) = \langle \phi(p), \phi(q) \rangle_{\Bbb R^3} \qquad p,q \in \mathscr P_2.
$$
Using the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces (an invertible linear transformation) and that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_{\Bbb R^3}$ is an inner-product, we can show that $( \cdot , \cdot)$ as defined above satisfies the [definition of an inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, thank you very much for the help! This makes sense, just one question: you say "we can show that...". Are you saying that a proof follows from the isomorphism and dot product you described, or are you saying that the presence of those two things _is_ the proof? 

Nonetheless, thinking of it while keeping that isomorphism in mind makes it much more intuitive, thanks again!

Comment: @NestDoberman I'm saying that there is a proof that $(\cdot, \cdot)$ is an inner product that uses only the fact that $\phi$ is an isomorphism and $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_{\Bbb R^3}$ is an inner product.  You're welcome